# Issues with Google appengine HRD migration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, database-migration

I migrated my database from Master slave to HRD (google appengine) and running into multiple issues:

- mis-match in number of entities

We had 81543 records before migration while there are only about 71669 records post migration. We are unsure why about several thousands of records are missing

Before migration -  http://snag.gy/bwbx2.jpg
post migration - http://snag.gy/r6IAo.jpg

- some records are accessible from datastore viewer, but fails to fetch them on querying with API

Ex: "users" table contained a user - demo1@xyz.com and the GQL query

```
select * from users where user_id='demo1@xyz.com'
```

API call which fails:

```
 Query query = new Query("users");
   query.addFilter("user_id", FilterOperator.EQUAL, request.getParameter("user_id"));

   // Get Datastore
   DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

   // PreparedQuery contains the methods for fetching query results
   // from the datastore
   PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);

   // Get Results
   for (Entity result : pq.asIterable())
   {
     System.out.println("result = " + result); 
   }
```

Can someone please help with this asap.

Thanks